# How to get the Year of a Temporal in Java

Tags: java, java-8, java-time

My problem is to find a useful method from the Temporal interface. In specific, I want to have the year from an Object, which is implementing the Temporal interface. All methods of the interface just add or sub from the objects, however, I just want to get the year of the Temporal itself.

Comment: `Temporal` has a base interface `TemporalAccessor`, which has a `get` method.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html, "Methods inherited from interface java.time.temporal.TemporalAccessor": [Get](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-)

Comment: I wonder why this question was put on hold because I don't see any aspect of 3rd-party libraries involved here. It is only about Java-8-stuff.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`Temporal`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html) interface inherits the [`TemporalAccessor::get`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/TemporalAccessor.html#get-java.time.temporal.TemporalField-) method, so for example you can do this:

```
Temporal t = LocalDate.now();
System.out.println(t.get(ChronoField.YEAR));
```

Output:

```
2018
```

**EDIT**

As [@Ole V.V. pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48990162/how-to-get-the-year-of-a-temporal-in-java/48990281#comment84985662_48990281) is good to validate if the `Temporal` implementation supports the desired field using [`Temporal::isSupported`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/temporal/Temporal.html#isSupported-java.time.temporal.TemporalUnit-):

```
if(t.isSupported(ChronoField.YEAR)){
   // ...
}
```

This will prevent getting exceptions if the `Temporal` implementation doesn't support the desired field. For example, [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a `Temporal` implementation that doesn't support the Year.

Comment: tanks for this fast and nice answer

Comment: Correct answer. Remember to check `t.isSupported​(ChronoField.YEAR)` first.

Answer (score 3):

its defined in its superInterface `TemporalAccessor`.

so you can get the year by,

```
int year = temporal.get(ChronoField.YEAR);
```

Comment: Thanks for this very fast answer ;)